# Python datetime "int object is not callable"

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime, date
now = datetime.now()
print now.day()
```

How come when this code gives an error "'int' object is no callable", is there even a use to now.day()?

Answer (score 4):

```
print now.day
```

is all you need

`datetime.day` is a property not a method and it returns the integer day ... so you are trying to call an integer when you add parentheses (ala `28()`, which also clearly would not work)